# Which plugins to uncheck and which plugins to check in android studio for flutter development

Tags: android, flutter

I have decided to uncheck some plugins [i think they are unnecessary for flutter development] In order to make android studio lighter.

PLease provide useful and useless plugins list for flutter development....

By the way I want to know if below mentioned plugins are useful or not?

1.Is kotlin plugin useful for flutter?
2.Markdown support plugin 
3.Markdown navigator plugin
4.Gauge
5.Android APK support
6.App link assistant
7.Android NDK support
8.Covergae
9.EditorConfig
10.Google cloud tools core 
11.Google cloud tools for android studio
12.118n for java
13.Groovy
14.Intellij configuration script
15.intellilang
16.java byte code decompiler
17.java stream debugger
18.JUnit
19.Kotlin
20.Mercurial integration'
21.properties support
22.Settings repository
23.smali support
24.Sub version
25.task management
26.test recorder
27.TestNG-J

Comment: This might help. https://www.android-examples.com/load-local-html-file-in-webview-on-android/ I think you can add multiple `HTML` files on your assets folder and as long as you minimize the use and optimize your images the size can be small because after all `HTML` files are just `text`. Just `loadUrl()` the next `HTML` file on `Button` click. It's up to you how you can cycle through your `HTML` file list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your html files in web server and load these html files as string

code snippet

```
_loadHtmlFromAssets() async {    
    String url = 'http://test.com/Android/sample.html';
    Response response = await get(url);
    // sample info available in response

    String fileText = response.body;

    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
  }
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HelpScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HelpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HelpScreenState createState() {
    return HelpScreenState();
  }
}

class HelpScreenState extends State<HelpScreen> {
  WebViewController _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Help')),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 300,
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: '',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                },
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.thumb_up,
                semanticLabel: 'Thumbs up',
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _loadHtmlFromAssets();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    //String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/help.html');
    String url = 'http://test.com/Android/sample.html';
    Response response = await get(url);
    // sample info available in response

    String fileText = response.body;

    _controller.loadUrl( Uri.dataFromString(
        fileText,
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')
    ).toString());
  }
}
```

demo

[image]